# Get index of last occurence of matched string?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the index of the *last* occurrence of a character in a string which is part of a match string. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Something like `match(/[\.,;]/g)` but I want the index in the original string of the *last* element of the returned array, the way that `match(/[\.,;]/)` gives the index of the *first* match.

E.g., if string is `Hello, this is a test. foo` I want the *index* of the *last* period/comma/semicolon.

The best solution I've come up with is reversing the string and finding first match:

```
text.length - text.split('').reverse().join('').match(/[\.,;]/).index - 1
```

Comment: @Nick But that will only allow searching for a single character, no? Or can I put a regex match into that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let text = 'Hello, this is a test. foo'; 
let lastChar = [...text.matchAll(/[\.,;]/g)].pop().index
console.log(lastChar)
```

Comment: @Dan, just to let you know, I edited my answer just now, the original wasn't returning the right value!

Comment: This was beautiful ... why not `[...text.matchAll(/[\.,;]/g)].pop().index` ? That seems to work great. I don't think we need the loop

Comment: ...and now it turns out After Effects doesn't support `matchAll` ... bummer

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hacky solution, but you can use a function as an argument to replace:

```js
const matches = [];
const text = "foo.bar,qaz";
// don't use any capturing groups otherwise the function will be messed up
text.replace(/[\.,;]/g, (match, offset) => matches.push(offset));
console.log(matches[matches.length - 1]);
```

Comment: This is nice ... I don't quite understand how it works! ... but I think symlink's is more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not efficient because this is go through every character  `text.length - text.split('').reverse().join('').match(/[\.,;]/).index - 1`.
You can simply using a for loop:
Run and check the code below:

```js
const text = "Hello, this is a test. foo"
const validChecker = [".",",",";"] // any char you want
const findLast = (text,validChecker) =>{
  if(!text) return
  for(let i = text.length -1; i>=0; i--){
    if(validChecker.includes(text[i])){
      return i
    }
  }
}

console.log(findLast(text,validChecker))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is infact a very good question to show one of the overlooked and most underrated string methods. `String.search()`. Which takes a regexp to do it's things and returns the index of the match or -1 if not found.

Get me the last one's index often calls for `.lastIndexOf()` yet sometimes when we search for optional targets then it is useless or not sufficient the least. Such as the last appearance of `"."`, `","` or `";"`. So here is your multiple choice `.lastIndexOf()` function.

```js
let s = ",., .;, ,...;; ;_-_,.;---",
    i = s.search(/[\.,;](?!.*[\.,;])/);
console.log(`The index is ${i} and the character at that position is "${s[i]}".`);
```